# Python3. NameError: name ' ' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, redis

Estoy usando PyQt5 con Python 3 y estoy tratando de importar redis, pero al hacer la conexion me da este error

named 'conexion' is not defined

el codigo lo tengo asi:

Logica:

```
import redis

Class Logica():

    conexion = redis.Redis()
    valores = None

    def Obtener_llaves(self):

        valores = conexion.key('*')

        for item in valores:
            return item
```

y la vista:

```
Class Inicio(QWidget):

    programa = None

    def __init__(self, programa):

            self.prorama = programa
            super().__init__()

            self.ListaBD_txt = QTextEdit(self)
            self.ListaBD_txt.setText("")

            self.Btn_Calcular = QPushButton(self)
            self.Btn_Calcular.clicked.connect(self.mostrar_todo)

    def mostrar_todo(self):

        try:
            valor = self.programa.Obtener_llaves()
            self.ListaBD_txt.setText(valor)

        except Exception as inst:
            print(type(inst))
            print(inst)
```

el main:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from logica import Logica
from redis-vista import Inicio

def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    sh = Inicio(Logica())
    sh.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

y ya definí conexion en la logica pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error y no se que pueda ser

Comment: puedes mostrar como haces la conexion?

Comment: listo agrege la parte en donde paso los parametros

Answer (score 2):

Hay algunos errores en tu código. Son errores, digamos "de python" y no de PyQt, por lo que para ilustrarlos y corregirlos prescindiré de `redis` o de `PyQt5` y todo lo demás, y me centraré en los conceptos.

Aparte del error de poner `Class` en mayúscula (supondré que ha sido un error al copiarlo y lo ignoraré), el problema es que haces cosas como esta:

```
class MiClase():
    variable = "valor"

    def funcion(self):
        # Intento de usar la variable
        print(variable)
```

Este sencillo ejemplo ya fallaría con el mismo problema que te ocurre a tí:

```
objeto = MiClase()
objeto.funcion()
```

> `NameError: name 'variable' is not defined`

La razón es que esa sintaxis por la que asignas variables en la propia declaración de la clase, para lo que sirve es para crear "atributos de clase". Es decir, `variable` es un atributo de la clase `MiClase`.

A diferencia de otros lenguajes como Java, no puedes referirte a un atributo de clase sin poner delante la clase en cuestión. Es decir, cuando en `funcion` intentamos acceder a `variable`, python no va a entender "automáticamente" que estás refiriendote a `MiClase.variable`. Tienes que hacerlo explícito:

```
class MiClase():
    variable = "valor"

    def funcion(self):
        # Intento de usar la variable
        print(MiClase.variable)
```

Esto hará desaparecer el error. Pero por otro lado ¿**Querías eso**? Es decir, ¿querías que `variable` fuera un atributo de clase  o estabas por el contrario intentando que fuera un atributo de objeto?

### Atributos de clase vs. atributos de objeto

La diferencia es que, cuando instancias esa clase por ejemplo así:

```
objeto = MiClase()
```

El atributo `variable` no pertenece a `objeto`, sino a la clase. A pesar de ello, puedes intentar acceder a ese atributo a través del objeto, por ejemplo estas dos líneas producirán el mismo resultado:

```
print(objeto.variable)
print(MiClase.variable)
```

Pero esto funciona porque la primera línea, al intentar buscar el atributo `variable` en el `objeto` y no encontrarlo, python buscará a continuación en la clase de la cual ha sido instanciado (y si ahí tampoco, en la clase de la cual hereda, etc.) hasta que lo encuentre. Por eso cualquiera de las dos líneas llega al mismo sitio.

**Ahora bien**, cuando *asignas* un valor nuevo a ese atributo, se puede caer en un error si no estás al tanto de lo que está pasando. ¿Qué crees que pasará si cambio el valor de `MiClase.variable`? Es decir ¿qué crees que imprimirá el código siguiente?

```
MiClase.variable = "Nuevo valor"
print(objeto.variable)
print(MiClase.variable)
```

Si has respondido que imprimirá en ambos casos `"Nuevo valor"`, estás en lo correcto. No hay sorpresas aquí. La asignación ha cambiado el valor del atributo de clase, y por tanto cuando volvemos a acceder a él, tanto a través de la clase como a través del objeto, encontramos el valor cambiado.

¿Y en este otro caso?

```
objeto.variable = "Sorpresa!"
print(objeto.variable)
print(MiClase.variable)
```

¿Qué saldrá aquí? Si pensaste que saldrá `"Sorpresa!"` dos veces, oh... malas noticias. Cuando intentas acceder a un atributo de un objeto *para cambiar su valor* y ese atributo no existe en el objeto ¡se crea uno nuevo!

Ahora `objeto` sí que tiene un atributo `variable`, y ya no usa el atributo de la clase. El valor `"Sorpresa!"` fue almacenado en el nuevo atributo de ese objeto. El atributo de la clase sigue con su valor original. Tenemos ahora dos atributos con el mismo nombre, uno en el objeto, el otro en la clase.

Esto suele ser fuente de problemas, por lo que en general los atributos de clase **no se usan mucho**.

En su lugar, se trabaja siempre con atributos de objeto, y estos se inicializan en el constructor `__init__`. Por tanto, otra implementación del ejemplo sería:

```
class MiClase():
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable = "valor"

    def funcion(self):
        # Intento de usar la variable
        print(self.variable)
```

En este código `self` se refiere siempre a una instancia concreta de un objeto. Así:

```
objeto = MiClase()
```

crea un nuevo objeto, llama a `objeto.__init__()` (pasándole el propio objeto a través de `self`) y en esa función se crea `objeto.variable` a través de la asignación `self.variable="valor"`. A partir de ahi, en cualquier otro método de ese objeto puedes usar `self.variable`.

Cada nueva instancia tendrá su propio atributo `variable`. No habrá uno del mismo nombre en la clase que pueda causar confusión

### Otra cosa

En tu código tenías también este extraño bucle:

```
    for item in valores:
        return item
```

Si tu intención era que en cada iteración del bucle se retorne un valor, no es eso lo que ocurrirá, ya que obviamente, una vez haces el primer `return` abandonas la función y ya no se seguirá ejecutando el bucle.

Para hacer algo similar a lo que quieres, debes usar `yield` en vez de `return`, pero esto convertirá ese método en un *generador*, lo que seguramente es materia para otra pregunta por lo que no me extiendo más.